# Twilio Video - Video stream from ethernet port

Tags: twilio-video

Iam developing a video application where the video from the USB Camera (Plugged in to a medical device) is sent to an Edge device on an ethernet port. The receiving video stream on the Edge device is processed before rending this stream on a web application.

Iam using Twilio SDK (Python & Javascript) to realize this.
However, I don't see any APIs in Twilio where I could inject a video stream before i join a video room. The APIs of Twilio always expect the video source to be a local camera and not a video stream from an external source.

is there a way to override this default behavior and provide video stream as a source to the APIs.

I looked at the Twilio API documentation including Twilio.Video.LocalVideoTrack, but couldn't figure out a way to realize this.